# If $_POST is empty

Tags: php

i don't know What I'm doing wrong, I used first javascript for warning me that a text box is empty. Since that was bugging and wouldn't work for all text box. If tried with if isset $_POST['submit'], So when I Submit the form and I forgot to insert a title I should receive an error 'No title added'

```
<?php
// POST.PHP POSTING NEW CONTENT
include 'config.php';
                            // values from form
                            if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
                            $id=$_POST['id'];
                            $title=$_POST['title'];
                            $pic=$_POST['pic'];
                            $youtube=$_POST['youtube'];
                            $cat=$_POST['cat'];
                            $NSFW=$_POST['NSFW'];



                            // insert data to mysql
                            $sql = "INSERT INTO post(id, title, pic, youtube, cat, NSFW)VALUES('$id', '$title', '$pic', '$youtube', '$cat', '$NSFW')";
                            $result=mysql_query($sql);
                            }
                            // succes added
                            if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
                            if($_POST['title']==""){
                            echo 'No title added'; }
                            if($_POST['pic']==""){
                            echo 'No image added.'; }
                            if($_POST['youtube']==""){
                            echo 'No youtube link added';}  
                            $id=$_POST['id'];
                            echo 'Yeah, buddy! Your content is added. Go to <a href="/category.php"/>CATEGORYS</a><br>';
                            }



                            // end of post script ^^
?>
```

Comment: You need to do  better job explaining your issue as it is not very clear

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: You can't have a GET and POST request at the same time so your first two if's will never succeed

Comment: if(isset($_GET['pic']))  breaks your logic. If you are not sure, you can use $_REQUEST instead $_GET and $_POST. In this way you will be able to debug. But using strict $_POST and $_GET is good practice

Comment: @Joren, of course you can - post your form to `yourfile.php?pic=hello`

Comment: @scrowler, yes, but in this case he dont use a url parameter.

Answer (score 3):

You are not checking correctly on this line:

```
if($_POST['title']=""){
```

and the same for other lines using the same concept.  It should be `==`:

```
if($_POST['title']==""){
```

You were basically saying to set the value to nothing then check if it's true.

---

Also, this:

```
if(isset($_GET['pic'])) {
```

should be:

```
if(isset($_POST['pic'])) {
```

since you never used a get request.

Comment: Still doesn't work, Just editted my thread explained more, what I mean.

Comment: I use $_GET for ?page=pic I've updated the script now I think I had it  on a wrong place.

Comment: You need to go through your script and examine what it is returning to see what the problem is.  Possibly you never press the submit button, but this is too open ended for anyone to answer it fully.

Comment: everythings works, As I said I used before javascript for inserting an empty row into mysql. He gave an error, But I want now just to use the if empty=='' function After I submit something I see `Yeah, buddy! Your content is added. Go to category`

Comment: Like I said, you would need to go through your script and see what it is returning to the variables.